# Does JSP only run a single instance of a JAR

Tags: java, jsp, jar, epub

I have a JSP that accepts an EPUB file as an upload and then uses a JAR file to do some checks/validations on the EPUB.

I got it to work fine but when I tested to use the JSP page from 2 different tabs, **tab1** and **tab2** and uploading a different file for each tab, the result for both pages are for only 1 of the tabs either tab1 or tab2 and the tomcat server shuts down afterwards.

I checked the console and it has a

> **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**

which I think is caused by my JAR file having static variables.

So my question is, does the JSP only run a single instance of my JAR even if I use 2 browsers?

If so, does fixing the static variables my only option or are there anything else I could do?

Comment: Perhaps you use the classes of the library in a wrong way? Or as you already suspected the library has been written in a way that does not allow parallel access... you should share some code. Is it an external lib that you use?

Comment: @home  thanks for the response, but I think I figured it out. It was the static variable that holds the result thats why I get only a single result. Thanks anyway :) im still just a newb on JSP

Comment: "single instance of a JAR" does not really make sense. A JAR does not have instances. It is just a container for class bytecodes and other resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each web application has only one classloader. The JSP (which is part of an web application) uses the JAR which is loaded only once. Hence static variables are shared between all requests and the content gets overwritten. You need to make the variables non-static and create a new instance in each JSP to do your processing.

Comment: I know it's kinda late but this is actually what I did, I removed all of the static variables in my JAR and created new instance in each JSP and my page worked great. Cheers @peterkofler